# How can i make pictures and text to stay on the same line and not change the position?

Tags: javascript, html

[image example - text is moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COvhL.gif)

My HTML page is empty, with only 3 span elements. Here is my javascript code how i insert my images:

```js
if (fahrenheitTemperature < 60) {
  let coldPicture = "./images/cold.png"
  let temperatureIcon = document.getElementById("temperatureIcon").innerHTML = `<h3> Current temperature: </h3> ${fahrenheitTemperature.toFixed(2)} Fahrenheit\xB0 <img src="${coldPicture}" height="50" width="50">`;
} else if (fahrenheitTemperature > 67) {
  let hotPicture = "./images/hot.png";
  let temperatureIcon = document.getElementById("temperatureIcon").innerHTML = `<h3> Current temperature: </h3> ${fahrenheitTemperature.toFixed(2)} Fahrenheit\xB0 <img src="${hotPicture}" height="50" width="50">`;

} else {
  document.getElementById("temperatureIcon").innerHTML = `<h3> Current temperature: </h3> ${fahrenheitTemperature} Fahrenheit\xB0`;
}

if (windCondition > 11) {
  let windPicture = "./images/wind.png";
  let windSpeed = document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = `<h3> Wind Speed: </h3> ${windCondition} mph wind <img src="${windPicture}" height="50" width="50">`;
} else {
  document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = `<h3> Wind Speed: </h3> ${windCondition} mph wind`;

}
```

Basically i want to insert a image when certain condition is met. But as you can see on the gif that i post, the text of Current Temperature and Wind Speed is moving (i think is going one line down) once the image is posted. How can i make that to stay on the same line and not moving at all, doesnt matter if there is a picture or no? I know i can do that with resizing the pictures and using smaller width and height but

Comment: Make the thermometer image `position:relative`.

Comment: You can put the image in the original HTML, with `visibility: invisible;` style.. This will reserve the space for the image, but not show it. When you want to show the image, change it to `visibility: visible;`.

Comment: You really should include the HTML in your snippet, But If I had to guess it has more to do with your combining block elements and inline elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you had only 3 spans and I don't know your requirements, but that javascript can really be cleaned up if you want to consider that constant text need not be part of the JS.

Also I added some values for the missing inputs

You can then use css to style the HTML.

```js
let fahrenheitTemperature = 59;
let windCondition = 10;

document.getElementById("spnTemp").innerText = fahrenheitTemperature.toFixed(2);
let img = document.getElementById("imgTemp");

if (fahrenheitTemperature < 60) {
  img.src = "./images/cold.png";
} else if (fahrenheitTemperature > 67) {
  img.src = "./images/hot.png";
} else {
  img.src = null;
}

document.getElementById("spnWind").innerText = windCondition.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("imgWind").src = (windCondition > 11 ? "./images/wind.png" : '');
```

```css
h3 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Current temperature:</h3>
  <span id="spnTemp"></span>&deg; Fahrenheit
  <img id="imgTemp" src="" height="50" width="50" />
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Wind Speed:</h3>
  <span id="spnWind"></span> mph Wind
  <img id="imgWind" src="" height="50" width="50" />
</div>
```

Comment: this one is working properly, however the img icon still stays on the page even if there is no img .. even when you load the page img icon is there, any idea how do i remove that?

Comment: yes on the conditions that have no image, style the `<img>` as `display:none`. you can do this via javascript or via css

Comment: or alternatively style them initially as hidden and then reveal them when the conditions require the image

Answer (score 0):

this is a common issue if you don't understand the difference between  browser `reflow` and `repaint` also reading about `Cumulative Layout Shift` understanding this will lead you to your own solution